# Image ratios gone after save (after server change - Typo3 8.7)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

After moving my TYPO3 app to another server I noticed something strange:
My custom image ratios don't really work anymore.
On the old server once an image was uploaded it would be cropped automatically like this:
[image: Old server working]
Now on the new server the image doesn't bother to crop itself :(
[image: New server Fail]
When I click on "Open Editor" it seems that it's working, but once I hit "Save" it's look just like at the beginning and nothing happened.
[image: Working on both]
**Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this could be, or even better - how to fix this?**

Comment: Did you give TYPO3 the according path to your gm-file in the Installtool?

Comment: @BastianBalthasarBux yeah, but there was no reaction of TYPO3

Comment: Is it the correct path? (root server path, may be you could find out by a php-info);
Does it have the rights to be executed?

Comment: @BastianBalthasarBux I double checked it, yes - I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the web hosting provider - and it worked immediatly with all the default settings...
The previous web hosting provider must've messed around with some settings or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit now says "exec" function of php is disabled (I guess, it's not shell_exec, which is most likely deactivated too, if I understand that right).

If you have access to php.ini you could enable it. Then also the orginally installed ImageMagick should work.

AFAIK if it is not activated, IM and GM won't work in TYPO3.
Maybe you should have a look at your error logs ... ;)
I am pretty sure, that error is written there. (Or also in installtool in the test-area)